# C language linux shell

Tags: c, shell

In the provided code snippet, I am seeking guidance on how to enhance its functionality. Specifically, I want to implement a feature where, when users enter commands other than the built-in ones (such as 'ls'), the shell should execute system commands as child processes. Moreover, I aim to establish an environmental entry, 'parent=/linShell,' in these child processes. This entry is intended to convey information about the parent shell's working directory. I would appreciate assistance in incorporating this enhancement into the existing code.

```
void execute_command(char* command, int background) {
        pid_t pid = fork();

        if (pid < 0) {
            perror("Fork failed");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        } else if (pid == 0) {

            // Child process
            if (background) {
                setsid(); // Run the process in a new session to detach it from the terminal
            }

            char* argv[] = { "/bin/sh", "-c", command, NULL };
            execv(argv[0], argv);

            // If execv fails
            perror("Execv failed");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        } else {
            // Parent process
            if (!background) {
                waitpid(pid, NULL, 0); // Wait for the child process to complete
            } else {
                // Print the background process ID (PID)
                printf("The command runs in background with ID: %d\n", pid);
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> I want to implement a feature where, when users enter commands other than the built-in ones (such as 'ls'), the shell should execute system commands as child processes.

You appear to be making progress on that.  The normal approach is to `fork()` a child process, and in it to use one of the `exec`-family functions to run the requested command.

HOWEVER, you are *not* running the requested command.  You are running a shell, and asking that to run the command.  It's not clear what you gain from doing that, because everything your shell needs to be able to do to run external commands directly (command line parsing, redirection (if supported), expansions, *etc*), it also needs to be able to do to run built-in commands.

Additionally, you probably do not want to detach the child from the terminal. You might want to put it in a different process group than the parent shell, but it is not normal to move even a background process to its own session.  Look instead to `tcsetpgrp()` to control which processes in the current session have access to the terminal.

> I aim to establish an environmental entry, 'parent=/linShell,' in these child processes. This entry is intended to convey information about the parent shell's working directory.

You say "working directory", but you seem to present a fixed string.  A shell's working directory is (typically) dynamic.  Its initial value is not predetermined, and the user can change it via (in Bourne-family and Csh-family shells) the `cd` command.

But that's a side issue.  The main question seems to be about how to get an entry into the process's environment, and that's easy.  Those of the `exec`-family functions that do not take an explicit environment forward the caller's environment to the new process image.  This means that all you have to do is add the wanted variable to the environment of the forked child before you call `execv()`.  For example:

```
        pid_t pid = fork();

        // ...
        if (pid == 0) {

            // Child process

            setenv("parent", "/linShell", 1);

            execv(argv[0], argv);

            // ...
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.

to be more clear, the requirement says "When users enter other commands (ls for example), the shell should invoke system's commands as child process with an environmental entry parent=<pathname>/linShell,".

Comment: @AzmirSabir, you should read the question as SO actually formats it.  No `<pathname>` appears.  It looks like you've fallen for an SO formatting gotcha.  But this still answers the question, and almost everything in it still applies.